# Check if date has passed

Tags: actionscript-3, date

I absolutely don't know how to check if date has passed in actionscript 3

Exemple : If the date 02/02/2015 has passed or not.

Can you help me please ?

I've succeed to only have the week number... I would prefer a precise date.

Thx,

---

EDIT
For the moment I've got this code :

```
function goActu(event:MouseEvent):void{

var dat:Date = new Date();
trace(dat);
trace(dat.month+1);
        if (dat.month+1 == 1){
        gotoAndStop( 18 );
    }
        if (dat.month+1 == 2){
        gotoAndStop( 19 );
    }
            if (dat.month+1 == 3){
        gotoAndStop( 20 );
    }
            if (dat.month+1 == 4){
        gotoAndStop( 21 );
    }
            if (dat.month+1 == 5){
        gotoAndStop( 22 );
    }
}
```

I'd like to precise the date like :

```
            if (dat.month+1 == 5 **&& date>15/05/2015**){
        gotoAndStop( 22 );
    }
            if (dat.month+1 == 6 **&& date>15/06/2015**){
        gotoAndStop( 22 );
    }
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more information on your question, I don't quite understand "Check if Date has Passed".

Passed what?

Comment: Sorry. If the date 02/02/2015 is passed or not (for exemple).

Comment: I don't understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a method in the Date class that returns the object (the date) represented in miliseconds since 1.1.1970 (or something linke that) to compare two dates, create a Date object for each date an compare this so called Unix timestamp of both of them. Afaik the method's name is getTime()

Answer (score 0):

```
public function compare (date1 : Date, date2 : Date) : Number
{
    var date1Timestamp : Number = date1.getTime (); // Input
    // Input your date -> The function will return amount in milseconds since Jan 1 / 1970
    var date2Timestamp : Number = date2.getTime (); // Compare
    // Input your date -> The function will return amount in milseconds since Jan 1 / 1970

    var result : Number = -1;

if (date1Timestamp == date2Timestamp)
{
    result = 0; // Their the same
}
else if (date1Timestamp > date2Timestamp)
{
    result = 0; // Hasn't Passed
}
else if (date1Timestamp < date2Timestamp)
{
    result = 1; // Passed Date
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Hmmm.. I would like to enter multiple dates time. I'll edit my post in order to explain it.